# How to SQL query elements which have more concrete variation of another attribute?

Tags: sql

A short example:

I need to query `Store_ID`s which have `Product_ID` 'product1' and 'product2'.

```
TableName:
Storage_items
    
+----+-------------+----------+
| ID | Product_ID  | Store_ID |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | product1    | store1   |
|  2 | product2    | store1   |
|  3 | product1    | store2   |
|  4 | product3    | store2   |
|  5 | product2    | store3   |
|  6 | product3    | store3   |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Store_ID`s which have `'product1'` and `'product2'` and maybe other `Product_ID`s too:

```
SELECT Store_ID 
FROM Storage_items
WHERE Product_ID IN ('product1', 'product2')
GROUP BY Store_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) = 2
```

If you want `Store_ID`s which have `'product1'` and `'product2'` only:

```
SELECT Store_ID 
FROM Storage_items
GROUP BY Store_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) = 2
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN Product_ID NOT IN ('product1', 'product2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `WHERE` statement should do the trick, I guess.

```sql
SELECT Store_ID
FROM Storage_items
WHERE Product_ID = "product1"
OR Product_ID = "product2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [and](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp):

```
SELECT Store_ID
FROM Storage_Items
WHERE Product_ID = 'product1'
AND Product_ID = 'product2'
```

Comment: I need AND condition for the problem. 'The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.'

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstood that, i will update it :)

Comment: Unfortunately the updated query is still not working. With AND in the WHERE means that one record's attribute has 2 value in the same time. This is not possible :(

Comment: BTW mention the IN operator was helpful :) I continued the search with looking for the IN + AND keywords